# android volley and "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" error

Tags: android, android-volley

I create ProgressDialog in the onCreate() of the activity and later on run volley request as below:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    checkAnswer(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    answerCheck("Error");
                }
            }
    )
```

The very first two lines in answerCheck are:

```
if (dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
```

but on dialog.dismiss() I get the "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" exception.
I read that volley callbacks are run on UI thread. Thus it seems the dialog is handled on the activity thread, not a background thread that volley creates to handle http requests.

What do I miss?

Comment: The callback is apparently not on "the original thread that created a view hierarchy"

Comment: I forgot to mention that sometimes it works, the problem is intermittent